# Check two excel files for common products with Python Pandas and pick the product with the lowest price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two excel files from two different wholesalers with products and stock quantity information.

Some of the products in the two files are common, so they exist in both files.
The number of products in the files is different e.g. the first has 65000 products and the second has 9000 products.
I need to iterate through the products of the first file based on the common column 'EAN CODE' and check if the current product exists also in the EAN column of the 2nd file.
Afterwards check which product  has the lower price (which has stock > 0)  and print the matching row of this product to another output excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime

import pandas

from utils import recognize_excel_type

dataframes = []
input_directory = 'in'
for file in os.listdir(input_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, file)
    if file.lower().endswith('xlsx') or file.lower().endswith('xls'):
        dataframes.append(
            pandas.read_excel(file_path)
        )
    elif file.lower().endswith('csv'):
        dataframes.append(
            pandas.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=';')
        )

combined_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Stock', 'EAN Code'])
for dataframe in dataframes:
    this_type = recognize_excel_type(dataframe)
    if this_type == 'DIFOX':
        dataframe.rename(columns={
            'retail price': 'Price',
            'availability (steps)': 'Stock',
            'EAN number 1': 'EAN Code',
        }, inplace=True)

        tuned_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
            dataframe[combined_dataframe.columns],
        )
        combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe.append(tuned_dataframe, ignore_index=True)
    elif this_type == 'ECOM_VGA':
        headers = dataframe.iloc[2]
        dataframe = dataframe[3:]
        dataframe.columns = headers
        dataframe.rename(columns={
            'Price (€)': 'Price',
            'Stock': 'Stock',
            'EAN Code': 'EAN Code',
        }, inplace=True)
        tuned_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
            dataframe[combined_dataframe.columns],
        )
        combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe.append(tuned_dataframe, ignore_index=True)
    elif this_type == 'MAXCOM':
        dataframe.rename(columns={
            'VK-Preis': 'Price',
            'Verfügbar': 'Stock',
            'EAN-Code': 'EAN Code',
        }, inplace=True)
        tuned_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
            dataframe[combined_dataframe.columns],
        )
        combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe.append(tuned_dataframe, ignore_index=True)

combined_dataframe.dropna(inplace=True)
combined_dataframe['Stock'].replace('> ?', '', inplace=True, regex=True)
combined_dataframe['Price'].replace('> ?', '', inplace=True, regex=True)

combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe.astype(
    {'Stock': 'int32', 'Price': 'float32'}
)

combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe[combined_dataframe['Stock'] > 0]

combined_dataframe = combined_dataframe.loc[combined_dataframe.groupby('EAN Code')['Price'].idxmin()]

combined_dataframe.to_excel('output_backup/output-{}.xlsx'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), index=False)

if os.path.exists('output/output.xlsx'):
    os.remove("output/output.xlsx")
combined_dataframe.to_excel('output/output.xlsx'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), index=False)
print('Output saved to output directory')

for file in os.listdir(input_directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, file)
    os.remove(file_path)
print('All input files removed')
```